# Finding Probability Distribution Parameters Satisfying a Particular Condition

Tags: probability-distributions, expectation, parameter-estimation

**Condition:** 
$$E[\text{max}(X,Y)]  \leq  E[\text{max}(K,Y)]$$

Here, $X,Y$ are random variables. $K$ is a constant. The distribution for $Y$ is known.

**Question one:**

Is it possible to find the distribution parameters for $X$ satisfying the above condition?

**Question two:**

Is it possible to find the distribution parameters for $X$ satisfying the above condition when $X,Y$ are non negative random variables and $K \geq 0$ ?

**Clarifications:**

Please note,

1) $X,Y$ can follow any probability distribution in the above two questions.

2) So the problem comes down to assuming a particular distribution for $X$ and finding the parameters of the distribution satisfying the above condition.

3) We can make other simplifying assumptions if required, such as $X$, $Y$ are independent.

**Special Case Related Question:**

Please note, the special case of finding the maximum of two independent log normally distributed random variables, which is required for a part of the answer for this present question, is considered here: [Expected Value of Maximum of Two Lognormal Random Variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1614050/expected-value-of-maximum-of-two-lognormal-random-variables)

Comment: Your question doesn't specify what distribution X may have, are you asking if for any arbitrary distribution one can find parameters for it so that the above is satisfied? Given the distribution of Y, and the constant K?

Comment: @frogeyedpeas  Yes, the question is generic to see if this holds for all distributions. If not, are there specific distributions for which this holds. Let me modify the question to highlight this. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: With no knowledge of the distribution of $X$, the notion of "distribution parameters for $X$" doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Are we assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: @Math1000 We can make assumptions on the distribution for X and find the parameters accordingly. I have modified the question now, please let me know if this is a well defined sensible question now. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Math1000 Yes, we can make the simplifying assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, since I presume it helps.

Comment: @Winther Please let me now if I should post this question on the statistics forum so it falls on to a broader audience or should I let this stay here for a while before doing that?

Comment: One reason I think you had little success is that the question is quite broad so people don't know where to start answering it. It might be better to narrow it down to specific random variables $X,Y$. You could also try to post it at Cross-Validated SE (if you do link to this post saying you tried here first with no success).

Comment: @Winther Makes sense. Thanks for your suggest and editing the question. I will reframe and link to other related questions, so it would be more tractable to start.