# Expected Value of Maximum of Two Lognormal Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

We have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ which are log normally distributed, with suitable parameters, what is the expected value for $\max(X,Y)$?

Given,

$$
X=e^{\mu+\sigma Z_{1}};\quad Y=e^{\nu+\tau Z_{2}};\quad Z_{1}\sim N(0,1);Z_{2}\sim N(0,1);
$$

$Z_{1}, Z_{2}$ can be assumed independent if it simplifies matters.

We need to find an expression for $$E[\text{max}(X,Y)]$$

Please note I have reached the step below, but am unsure how to proceed further.

## Steps Tried

\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left[\max\left(X,Y\right)\right]=\int_{0}^{\infty}xf_{Y}\left(x\right)F_{X}\left(x\right)dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}yf_{X}\left(y\right)F_{Y}\left(y\right)dy
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}xf_{Y}\left(x\right)F_{X}\left(x\right)dx{\displaystyle =\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\tau}\phi\left(\frac{\ln x-\nu}{\tau}\right)}\Phi\left(\frac{\ln x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)dx
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
{\displaystyle =\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\tau}\phi\left(\frac{\ln x-\nu}{\tau}\right)}\Phi\left(\frac{\ln x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)dx\quad\text{, Substitution }u=\left(\frac{\ln x-\nu}{\tau}\right)\Rightarrow du=\frac{1}{x\tau}dx
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
{\displaystyle =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{u\tau+\nu}\phi\left(u\right)}\Phi\left(\frac{u\tau+\nu-\mu}{\sigma}\right)du
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
{\displaystyle =e^{\nu}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{u\tau}\phi\left(u\right)}\Phi\left(\frac{u\tau+\nu-\mu}{\sigma}\right)du
\end{eqnarray*}

## Related Question

Please note, an earlier question considers the case where there is only one source of randomness. This earlier question was mis-phrased due to my limited knowledge; but still provides an interesting and instructive solution.

[Expected Value of Maximum of Two Lognormal Random Variables with One Source of Randomness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1609392/expected-value-of-maximum-of-two-lognormal-random-variables-with-one-source-of-r)

Please let me know of any other suggestions …

Comment: Hint: $\max{a,b}=\max\{\log(a),\log(b)\}$ if $a,b>0$

Comment: Your first identity has some issues: it appear that the indicator functions for $X>Y$ and $X\le Y$ are not considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WLOG, we assume that $\sigma>0$ and $\tau >0$. Then
\begin{align}
E(\max(X, Y)) &= \iint\limits_{\mu+\sigma z_1 \ge \nu + \tau z_2}e^{\mu+\sigma z_1}\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(z_1^2+z_2^2)}dz_1 dz_2 \\
&\quad +  \iint\limits_{\mu+\sigma z_1 \le \nu + \tau z_2}e^{\nu+\tau z_2}\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(z_1^2+z_2^2)}dz_1 dz_2.
\end{align} 
Making the substitutions
\begin{align*}
x = \frac{\sigma z_1 - \tau z_2}{\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2}} \mbox{ and } y = \frac{\tau z_1 + \sigma z_2}{\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2}},
\end{align*}
we obtain that
\begin{align*}
& \ \iint\limits_{\mu+\sigma z_1 \ge \nu + \tau z_2}e^{\mu+\sigma z_1}\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(z_1^2+z_2^2)}dz_1 dz_2\\
=&\ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy \int_{\frac{\nu-\mu}{\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2}}}^{\infty}e^{\mu+\sigma \frac{\sigma x + \tau y}{\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2}}}\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)}dxdy\\
=&\ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy \int_{\frac{\nu-\mu}{\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2}}}^{\infty}e^{\mu+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2}\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left[\big(x-\frac{\sigma^2}{\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2}}\big)^2+\big(y-\frac{\sigma\tau}{\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2}}\big)^2\right]}dxdy\\
=&\ \int_{\frac{\nu-\mu}{\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2}}}^{\infty}e^{\mu+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\big(x-\frac{\sigma^2}{\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2}}\big)^2}dx\\
=&\ \int_{-\infty}^{-\frac{\nu-\mu}{\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2}}}e^{\mu+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\big(x+\frac{\sigma^2}{\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2}}\big)^2}dx\\
=&\ e^{\mu+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2} N\left(\frac{-\nu+\mu+\sigma^2}{\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2}} \right),
\end{align*}
where $N$ is the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal random variable. Similarly,
\begin{align*}
\iint\limits_{\nu + \tau z_2 \ge \mu+\sigma z_1}e^{\nu+\tau z_2}\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(z_1^2+z_2^2)}dz_1 dz_2 &= e^{\nu+\frac{1}{2}\tau^2} N\left(\frac{-\mu+\nu+\tau^2}{\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2}} \right).
\end{align*}
That is, 
\begin{align*}
E(\max(X, Y)) &= e^{\nu+\frac{1}{2}\tau^2} N\left(\frac{-\mu+\nu+\tau^2}{\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2}} \right) + e^{\mu+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2} N\left(\frac{-\nu+\mu+\sigma^2}{\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2}} \right).
\end{align*}

> **Alternative solution.**

Note that
\begin{align*}
\max(X, Y) &= Y + \max(X-Y, \ 0)\\
&= Y + Y\max\Big(\frac{X}{Y}-1, \ 0\Big).
\end{align*}
Let $P$ be the given probability measure, and $Q$ be a probability measure that is defined by the Randon-Nykodim derivative
\begin{align*}
\frac{dQ}{dP} = e^{-\frac{1}{2}\tau^2 + \tau Z_2}.
\end{align*}
Then 
\begin{align*}
\widehat{Z}_1 = Z_1, \mbox{ and } 
\widehat{Z}_2 = Z_2 - \tau
\end{align*}
are two standard independent normal random variables under the probability measure $Q$.
Moreover,
\begin{align*}
Z \equiv \frac{X}{Y} &= e^{\mu-\nu - \tau^2 + \sigma \widehat{Z}_1 - \tau \widehat{Z}_2}\\
&= e^{\mu-\nu - \tau^2 + \sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2} \xi},
\end{align*}
where 
\begin{align*}
\xi = \frac{\sigma \widehat{Z}_1 - \tau \widehat{Z}_2}{\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2}}
\end{align*}
is a standard normal random variable. Let
\begin{align*}
\lambda = \frac{-\mu+ \nu + \tau^2}{\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2}},
\end{align*}
and $E_Q$ be the expectation operator under the measure $Q$.
Then,
\begin{align*}
E\big(\max(X, Y) \big) &= E(Y)+E\big(Y\max(Z-1, \ 0) \big)\\
&=E(Y)+e^{\nu+\frac{1}{2}\tau^2} E_Q\big(\max(Z-1, \ 0) \big).
\end{align*}
Furthermore, 
\begin{align*}
E_Q\big(\max(Z-1, \ 0) \big) &= E_Q\left(Z\,\mathbb{I}_{Z \ge 1}\right) - E_Q\left(\mathbb{I}_{Z \ge 1}\right)\\
&=\int_{\lambda}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\mu-\nu -\tau^2 + \sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2} z -\frac{1}{2}z^2} dz - N(-\lambda)\\
&=e^{\mu-\nu + \frac{1}{2} (\sigma^2-\tau^2)} \int_{\lambda}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\big(z-\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2}\big)^2} dz - N(-\lambda)\\
&=e^{\mu-\nu + \frac{1}{2} (\sigma^2-\tau^2)}N\Big(\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2} -\lambda\Big) - N(-\lambda).
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
E\big(\max(X, Y) \big) &= e^{\nu + \frac{1}{2}\tau^2} \bigg[1 + e^{\mu-\nu + \frac{1}{2} (\sigma^2-\tau^2)}N\Big(\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2} -\lambda\Big) - N(-\lambda) \bigg]\\
&=e^{\nu + \frac{1}{2}\tau^2} N(\lambda) + e^{\mu + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2}N\Big(\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2} -\lambda\Big)\\
&= e^{\nu + \frac{1}{2}\tau^2}N\left(\frac{-\mu+ \nu + \tau^2}{\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2}}\right) +  e^{\mu + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2}N\left(\frac{-\nu+\mu+\sigma^2}{\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2}} \right).
\end{align*}

> Comments.
>   You can make this question more general by assuming that
>   \begin{align*}
> X=e^{\mu+\sigma Z_1} \quad \mbox{and} \quad Y = e^{\nu+\tau\big(\rho Z_1 + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} Z_2\big)},
> \end{align*}
>   where $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are two independent standard normal random variables, and $|\rho|<1$. In this case, the measure $Q$ can be defined by
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{dQ}{dP} = e^{-\frac{1}{2}\tau^2 + \tau \big(\rho Z_1 + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} Z_2\big)}.
> \end{align*}
>   Moreover,
>   \begin{align*}
> \widehat{Z}_1 = Z_1 - \rho\tau, \mbox{ and }
> \widehat{Z}_2 = Z_2 - \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\tau
> \end{align*}
>   are two standard independent normal random variables under the probability measure $Q$. See also this question at https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/21361/how-to-use-a-change-of-numeraire-to-price-this-option/21375#21375.

Comment: Super. But shouldn't: $$\begin{align*}
E(\max(X, Y)) &= e^{\nu+\frac{1}{2}\tau^2} N\left(-\frac{-\mu+\nu+\tau^2}{\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2}} \right) + e^{\mu+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2} N\left(\frac{-\nu+\mu+\sigma^2}{\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2}} \right).
\end{align*}$$  be  $$\begin{align*}
E(\max(X, Y)) &= e^{\nu+\frac{1}{2}\tau^2} N\left(\frac{-\mu+\nu+\tau^2}{\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2}} \right) + e^{\mu+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2} N\left(\frac{-\nu+\mu+\sigma^2}{\sqrt{\sigma^2+\tau^2}} \right).
\end{align*}$$  ... can you check the minus sign ...

Comment: Thanks @wolfies. I made the corrections.

Comment: @Gordon Thanks for this detailed, clear and wonderful answer. One possibly trivial question regarding the, "WLOG, we assume that $\sigma >0$ and  $\tau>0$" Are there cases where these two can be negative? Is there some sort of space where variances can be negative or some such advanced concept?

Comment: @user249613: If $\sigma<0$, then we write $X$ as $X=e^{\mu +(-\sigma)(-Z_1)}$, where $-Z_1$ is also a standard normal random variable. The variance is always positive. However, as it is not specified that $\sigma$ is a standard deviation here, it is possible to have $\sigma <0$.